# ListView doesn't scroll automatically

Tags: android, listview

My ListView doesn't scroll automatically, so where there are more than a few items I do not have access to it (id does not fit the screen). I think it is about my xml file. Most answers I found in this topic was about the situation where there is a list view and the scroll bar. I was trying to do this that way but with no result. Can you tell me where the mistake is?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/getName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/getDuration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="send"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getListButton"
            android:text="getList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="getVideoList"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/videoList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

As G. Blake suggested maybe the problem is in my adapter. Here is the code connected to it:

```
List<String> videosNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Video v : videos){
            videosNames.add(v.getTitle());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,videosNames);
        videoList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What happens when you set layout_height to "match_parent" in your LinearLayout? (and possibly layout_height to "match_parent" in your ListView)

Comment: Why do you have height=0dp in the ListView? That way, the scroll length = 0, that's what I think

Comment: Matt, SebasSBM - these are values I found during looking for solution before I came here. Changing them as you said doesn't make the difference. Can AVD be the reason?

Comment: I think it's definitely a problem with your xml. I'm a bit suspicious about the layout_weight in ListView, too, seeing as there are no other weights declared. Looks to me like it could be removed?

Comment: the weight can be removed, and height can be changed to wrap_content, that should change it.

Comment: RED - I already checked that option - doesn't work, still the same.

Comment: Your XML looks fine to me.  Height = 0 and weight = 1 is just what you want.  I'm going to guess that the problem in in your adapter.

Comment: I edit my question post and add an adapter code to it.

Comment: did you try android:layout_height="match_parent" in your linear layout

Comment: yeah. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a RelativeLayout and put the ListView below all the other items. Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/getName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/getDuration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/getName"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:layout_below="@id/getDuration"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getListButton"
        android:text="getList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="getVideoList"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/videoList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/getListButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It might be better to add those other views to the ListView header instead and having just the ListView be a part of this layout.

Comment: I did as in your code above. All items but listview are one on the another o.O and list view us still unscrollable. Later I will check with list header.

Comment: Try it now. I have edited the code. Notice the layout_below on each item.

Comment: Looks fine but ListView is still unscrollable. As I said - on option with ListHeader I will check later (my little son doesnt want me to code :P)

Answer (score 0):

It started to work after restart of environment.Thanks everyone for interest.